# XSL: including a tag only if the original file has that tag

Tags: xslt

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I know very little about XSL and so I have failed to apply other answers I have found.

```
<node>
  <xsl:attribute name='TEXT'><xsl:value-of select='@text' /></xsl:attribute>
  <richcontent TYPE="NOTE"><xsl:value-of select='@_note' /></richcontent>
</node>
```

So what I need is to create the `<richcontent>` tag *only* if the `@_note` element exists in the original document. If it is absent, I don't want to create the `<richcontent>` tag in the new document.

I suspect I need something like "when", but I'm not sure how to use it. When I try the following

```
<node>
  <xsl:when test='@_note'>
    <richcontent TYPE="NOTE"><xsl:value-of  select='@_note' />
    </richcontent>
  </xsl:when>
</node>
```

I get this error

```
 element when is not allowed within that context
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide an excerpt of the source XML.

Comment: **1.** An example of the input would be helpful - and so would seeing your code in context. -- **2.** I believe you are misusing some terms here: it seems that the  `_note` node is an **attribute**, not an **element**. And what you are creating is definitely an **element**, not a **tag**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be no `@_node` element, because this is not a [valid QName](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName#Formal_definition), because it starts with the '@' character. QNames can only start with `:`, `_`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, or some UniCode characters described in the link above.

Your `<xsl:when>` approach to a solution is invalid, because `<xsl:when>` is only valid in the context of `<xsl:choose>` like this:

```
<node>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test='@_note'>
      <richcontent TYPE="NOTE">
        <xsl:value-of  select='@_note' />
      </richcontent>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</node>
```

But you need to rename your element `@_note` to something that conforms to the QName specification.

Comment: works beautifully, thanks! The thing with the @_note is clear. I was talking about a tag with that attribute.

Comment: @MrLMrK: Glad to read that. If you just misnamed `@_note` as an element rather than as an attribute - that can happen ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is thrown because `xsl:when` must be a child of `xsl:choose`.

In your case, when you have no alternative `xsl:when` or `xsl:otherwise` instructions, you should be using `xsl:if` instead.

Alternatively (and perhaps preferably), you could use a template matching the node in question: if the node does not exist, the template will not be applied, and the new element will not be created.